# Align paper-tabs to the right of paper-icon-button and main-title and inside app-toolbar in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am trying to achieve a similar layout to https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview

This currently what I have:

```
<app-header-layout bleeding>
            <app-header condenses reveals snaps shadow>
                <app-toolbar>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                    <div main-title flex>My App</div>
                    <paper-tabs scrollable bottom-item selected="0">
                        <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
                    </paper-tabs>
                </app-toolbar>
            </app-header>
```

and

```
        paper-tabs {
            max-width: 640px;
            --paper-tabs-selection-bar: {
                height: 5px;
            };
            --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--app-primary-color);
        }
```

Yet, all the elements are displaying on top of one another, instead of all the way to the right.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijtrZ.jpg)

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry. I must further add that I would like paper-tabs to be aligned all the way to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<app-header-layout>
  <app-header>
    <app-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button id="button" icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <div class="title" main-title>App name</div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="flex"></div>
        <paper-tabs scrollable selected="0">
          <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
      </div>
    </app-toolbar>
  </app-header>
  <div>
    main content
  </div>
</app-header-layout>
```

and

```
paper-tabs {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
  @apply(--layout-horizontal);
}

.flex {
  @apply(--layout-flex);
}
```

Note that, if you really want to use the `scrollable` attribute you need to specify the `paper-tabs`'s width. Otherwise just remove the `min-width` and the `scrollable` attribute and it should be good. Don't forget to import `iron-flex-layout` also.

Comment: Thank you very much. It now works. However, the <paper-icon-button> is not clickable. I am not sure if its related. If I remove the <paper-tabs> altogether then <paper-icon-button> becomes clickable again.

Comment: I found a fix to this. I just add margin-left: 100px to .bottom

However, this seems like a big hack. I was hoping that Polymer would have an elegant solutions for aligning elements inside <app-toolbar> without them piling on top of each other.

Comment: As I see it they usually use a larger `app-toolbar` if the tabs needed so the bottom part is below the title and buttons. I try to fix the button click problem and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AtipAsvanund I edited my answer, basically removed the `bottom-item` attribute and added `margin-top: auto` to the `bottom` css class.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.